# Installing QT on -- ubuntu linux -- few questions

Tags: linux, qt

I have installed QT5.1 on my host linux platform.

Now i am getting an error while opening Qt creator from `dashboard` :---

```
qt creator linux cannot overwrite file /home qt version xml
```

This link suggest how to get rid of this error, I followed it & above error is resolved :--
https://askubuntu.com/questions/253785/cannot-overwrite-file-home-baadshah-config-qtproject-qtcreator-toolchains-xml

.config folder contains :---

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/.config$ ls
dconf               goa-1.0   QtProject       update-notifier
gnome-disk-utility  ibus      QtProject.conf  user-dirs.dirs
gnome-session       nautilus  Trolltech.conf  user-dirs.locale
```

My PATH variable is :---

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/.config$ $PATH
bash: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

qt creator executable, is here :---

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/.config/QtProject$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 5 dinesh dinesh 4096 Nov 19 21:48 qtcreator
-rw-r--r-- 1 dinesh dinesh 3072 Nov 18 02:56 QtCreator.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 dinesh dinesh 5739 Nov 19 21:53 QtCreator.ini
```

Which command is not able to locate qt creator executable :---

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/.config/QtProject$ which qtcreator
dinesh@ubuntu:~/.config/QtProject$
```

I have installed QT in /opt/Qt5.1.1 folder :--

```
dinesh@ubuntu:/opt/Qt5.1.1$ ls
5.1.1                Licenses             MaintenanceTool.ini  README.txt
components.xml       MaintenanceTool      network.xml          Tools
InstallationLog.txt  MaintenanceTool.dat  qt-project.org.html
```

Now I have few questions :---
1> In $PATH enviromental variable we have not mentioned the location of QTcreator then how dashboard is able to open QTcreator ?
2> Also what exactly is the difference between these two folders , `~/.config` &  `/opt/Qt5.1.1` ?
3> How can i make my QT project to compile against library QT4.8.5 ? Do i have to make some changes in ~/.config ?
4> If i install QT4.8.5 does it install seprate QTcreator for itself ?

`Please suggest` so that i come to know how everything works in synchronization with each other ?

Comment: Instead of this, you can install the Qt development package from the Ubuntu repositories (package `libqt4-dev`) and Qt Creator (package `qtcreator`

Comment: Can i not compile my QT4.8 library from source & use it in current QT creator ?